# Trouble with iFrame and jQueryMobile on Android

Tags: android, url, jquery-mobile, iframe

my english is not sooo good, but i will try to explain my problem.

at first to my Page:
I load a iFrame on my that contains a formular. To make that usable for users with mobile-devices, i load jQuery 1.8.2. and jQueryMobile 1.2.0.

That works fine but on Android 2.x, the systembrowser loading the URL of the iFrame into the Adressbar. So the User can`t refresh the page correctly when he use the url inside the adressbar - so it loads only the iFrame

The refreshbutton of the browser works against this fine and refresh the correct Content.

Thats Problem appears only with Android 2.x devices. On newer Versions or iOS the iFrame works correct.

I Hope anybody understand my Problem and can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to disabled AJAX for jQuery-Mobile in the iFrame with this Script bevore you load jQueryMobile:

```
$(document).live("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

This ist not working with the new Version 1.9.2